# SimpleNamingContextBuilder does not support [javax.naming.Name] on standalone project using spring

Tags: spring, datasource, jndi, jta

I am trying to write a standalone project using spring with jtaDataSource.To bind data source to context ,I am using SimpleNamingContextBuilder before initialising applicationContext.Everything is working perfect when I use property name  dataSource with entityManagerFactory bean,but when I want to use jtaDataSource it gives me that error **"org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [javax.transaction.TransactionManager]"** and also **"javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: SimpleNamingContext does not support [javax.naming.Name]"**

exception with detail :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [javax.transaction.TransactionManager]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(WeblogicJtaPlatform.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.retrieveTransactionManager(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.getTransactionManager(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.TransactionManagerBasedSynchronizationStrategy.canRegisterSynchronization(TransactionManagerBasedSynchronizationStrategy.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.canRegisterSynchronization(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.attemptToRegisterJtaSync(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.pulse(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1584)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:407)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:560)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:288)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.getDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider.fromEntityManager(PersistenceProvider.java:295)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.<init>(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.createRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.doCreateRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.createRepositoryFactory(TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:227)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: SimpleNamingContext does not support [javax.naming.Name]
    at org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContext.getNameParser(SimpleNamingContext.java:287)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(InitialContext.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:135)
    ... 56 more
```

Java class defined as below :

```
   @SuppressWarnings("resource")
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

         activateDataSourcesOnContext();

      } catch (IllegalStateException | NamingException e) {

         logger.error("Error on activateDataSourceOnContext {}", e.getMessage(), e);
      }

      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

      logger.debug("ApplicationContext has been up");
   }

   /*
    * Before Initializing ApplicationContext,we have to create mock context and
    * bind datasource to it due to not using a real container[Application server
    * etc.]
    */
   private static void activateDataSourcesOnContext() throws IllegalStateException, NamingException {

      SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
      builder.bind(CressScheduleProperties.CREWDB_CONN_JNDI_NAME, CressScheduleDBUtil.getDataSource());
      builder.activate();

   }
```

applicationContex defined as below :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="xJndi" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- ################################################################################################################ -->

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.x.jpa" />
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="validationMode" value="NONE" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>

            ....

            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform
            </prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- ################################################################################################################ -->

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />


<jpa:repositories base-package="com.x.repo" />
```

Comment: Why do you want to use JTA on a standalone project? Why the added complexity?\

Comment: My purpose of using JTA is only to give management of the transactions to application server [I am connecting weblogic via jndi].

Comment: So then it isn't a standalone application, next to that are you really sure you want to use classes designed and used for testing as real classes. Nor will it work as hibernate expects to run in WebLogic so you would also need to have a different hibernate setup.

Comment: I know SpringNamingContextBuilder is using for mock,but I couldn't find a solution running standalone project with datasource.Because it expects to bind datasource to context before initiliasing applicationContext.